# Fastest way to add components to Jpanel

Tags: java, performance, swing

I am testing how time-consuming is placing components in a panel.
As a test example I am placing some hundreds components to a jPanel. I am looking for a faster way to place them. Here is my test code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPane {
  JFrame Myframe;
  JPanel Mypanel;


  public void createUI()
  {

    Myframe = new JFrame("Test clicks");
    Mypanel = new JPanel();
    Myframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    Myframe.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    Myframe.add(Mypanel);
    Myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Myframe.setVisible(true);

    //ADD 100+1 LABELS
    long start_time = System.nanoTime();//START TIME
    for (int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
      JLabel myLabel= new  JLabel();
      myLabel.setText("label"+ i);
      Mypanel.add(myLabel);
    }

    long end_time = System.nanoTime(); //START TIME
    double difference = (end_time - start_time)/1000000;

   //ADD EXECUTION TIME LABEL
   JLabel MyInfo= new  JLabel();
   MyInfo.setText("milliseconds:"+ difference);
   MyInfo.setBackground(Color.yellow);
   MyInfo.setOpaque(true);
   Mypanel.add(MyInfo);

   Myframe.pack();
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyPane overlapPane = new MyPane();
    overlapPane.createUI();
 }

 }
```

In my pc adding 1000 Jlabels takes 120 millliseconds. Of course execution time will vary greatly depending on hardware, Os etc.

My question is: Is there a faster way to place many components in a panel. Is there a way, for example, to place all of them at once? Would that make any difference?

EDIT: I would like to clarify that putting 1000 labels one just after the other is not what I am trying to achieve in any real world software I am developing, although I have the right to do it. It's just a example, and that I know that in some cases there can be more efficient ways to show large amount of text information on screen. Also, my question is not about software optimization in general, but It's only about testing this specific algorithm.

Comment: I think this is a rather meaningless question without more context.  For example, add one `JList` consisting of 1000 items with default cell renderer (which might use a single `JLabel`) and you might find it is a lot faster.  But even without that, is this truly the bottleneck in the app.?

Comment: @ Andrew Tompson. I simplified the case to see how adding components affects performance.

Comment: Sometimes cases can be oversimplified and I think that is what happened here, in case that was not clear.

Comment: Is 120 seconds really something that matters?

Comment: The loading part of any application (may it be a game, an IDE , a video editing program, etc.) always takes some time. I don't think 120ms is critical in your case!

Comment: It's just an example. My question is if there is a way to make this simple component creation procedure faster.

Comment: In that case I'm curious about the answer to that. I would suggest you edit your post to make it clearer that this is just an example for the sake of the question.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<100 ; i++){`  BTW - that code is adding *100* objects, not *1,000*.

Answer (score 1):

This adds *1,000,000* viewable objects in 196 nano-seconds.

[image]

Like I said, it depends on the context, and is quite an arbitrary question.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;

class ManyObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                for (int ii=0; ii<=1000000; ii++) {
                    v.add(ii);
                }
                long end = System.nanoTime();

                int duration = (int)((end-start)/1000000);
                v.add(duration);

                JList<Integer> list = new JList<Integer>(v);
                System.out.println("Duration in seconds: " + duration);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example adds integers to a JScrollPane. What about Jlabels to Panel? :)

Comment: *"What about Jlabels to Panel?"*  Why should we ***care***?  That is simply purile, with no applications in the *real world*.

Comment: If one doesn't care can simply ignore the question. And, anyway how fast a component is added in panel has to do with software performance. If one proves that it matters very little, little enough to ignore, that's still an answer. If one says that the way components are added in my test is the best that's still an answer.

Comment: *"If one doesn't care can simply ignore the question"*  I care that a newbie stumbling across this nonsense could mistake it for sense.  If you don't want answers in whatever form they are offered, you can always stop asking questions.

Comment: I am relatively newbie and I can live with it. What's wrong with asking if an algorythm is the best possible? No matter if it really doesn't make alot difference?

Comment: +1 for leveraging the _flyweight_ pattern used by `JList/JTable` renderers.

Comment: *"What's wrong with asking if an algorythm is the best possible?"*  1) [Premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  2) You described an arbitrary situation which is better handled with a `JList`.

Comment: BTW - if you wanted the list to read out as "labelNN", that is simply a matter of providing a custom renderer for the list (as it was constructed).

Comment: I think what @AndrewThompson is trying to say (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that the context and the number of times in which an element is added is independent of the performance of its _add_ method, which would be the limiting factor.

Comment: I just wanted to be the one to tip you over. Happy 100k! :)

Comment: @peeskillet  Consider me tipped.  :)